# How to get distinct values from table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a table with 20 columns, and I like to get distinct values of each column

So if I have

```
A  B  C  D ....
----------
z  c  c  d 
z  f  c  f 
a  c  f  d 
z  c  c  d 
b  f  b  d 
z  c  a  d
```

I want to get back

```py
{ 'A':[z,a,b],
  'B':[c,f],
  'C': [c,f,b,a]
  'D': [d,f]
....
}
```

How would the query look like ?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to do 4 queries

Comment: which tag was wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need in

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT a) a,
       array_agg(DISTINCT b) b,
       array_agg(DISTINCT c) c,
       array_agg(DISTINCT d) d
FROM test;
```

?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=47f1a3c2d50129ba7af568a901bbfc45)